# Asp.Net MVC: Html.ActionLink is adding a wierd text to my URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I recently deployed my asp.net mvc to a Windows-based hosting using Plesk.

Everything was working fine locally, but once I deployed the app I noticed that all my links had the string "aa" instead of language code:

```
mydomain.com/aa/Account/Register
```

instead of

```
mydomain.com/en/Account/Register
```

I suspect it has to do with the fact that I created an extension of Html.ActionLink as follows:

```
    private static string GetLocalizedController(string controllerName, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        if (cultureInfo == null) cultureInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;

        // arrange a "localized" controllerName to be handled with a dedicated localization-aware route.
        string localizedControllerName = String.Format("{0}/{1}",
            cultureInfo.TwoLetterISOLanguageName, controllerName);

        return localizedControllerName;
    }

    public static IHtmlString ActionLink( this HtmlHelper helper, string linkText, string actionName, 
        string controllerName, object routeValues, string htmlAttributes, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        string localizedControllerName = GetLocalizedController(controllerName, cultureInfo);

        return helper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, localizedControllerName, routeValues, htmlAttributes);
    }
```

This is the way I use it:

```
@Html.ActionLink("LinkText", "Index", "Home", null, null, (CultureInfo)null)
```

And this is how I put the language into the url:

```
public class LocalizedControllerActivator : IControllerActivator
{
    public IController Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        //Get the {language} parameter in the RouteData
        string lang = requestContext.RouteData.Values["lang"].ToString();

        if (lang != ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultLanguage"])
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(lang);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException(String.Format("ERROR: Invalid language code '{0}'.", lang));
            }
        }

        return DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(controllerType) as IController;
    }
}
```

But in localhost it works, I don't know what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` get the culture, by default, from the **server** not client

hence it is possible that the location you deployed the application to had a language set to `aa`, where as your local machine probably is a `en` culture.

I am guessing you wanted to get the culture of the client - i.e the person browsing your site

if so, try set

```
<system.web>
    <globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto"  />
<system.web>
```

more info about localization checkout 
https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/mar/27/auto-selecting-cultures-for-localization-in-aspnet

Comment: You were right... somehow the uiCulture was set to "aa-DJ" in that line of my web.config. That's weird because the code un my laptop is good. Anyway, thanks.